# jQuery .click() function - linking between two .click() functions (on seperate pages) and bringing up the related content

Tags: jquery, function, click

Okay, so I've got two .click() functions on two pages, which both work fine, no problem there.  I need to be able to link from within one of the .click() functions to the other.  How should the links be written or is the .click() function not right for this kind of process??  Linking to the page is fine ie. other content, but I want to be able to bring up the content from, lets say, 'changeText3' when the otherpage.html loads without having to click on the link on that page.

LOL, hope that's not too confusing.

```
<ul id="subNav">                                
    <li><a id="changeText1">&nbsp;Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="changeText2">&nbsp;Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="changeText3">&nbsp;Link 3</a></li>
</ul>  

<div id="textBox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tempor tincidunt varius. Cras adipiscing lacinia rhoncus. Suspendisse felis velit, dignissim scelerisque sodales vitae, hendrerit nec lorem.</p> 
    <p>Contact us <a href="contact.html">here.</a></p>
</div><!--end of textBox-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.v1.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $("#changeText1").click(function() {
            $("#textBox").html("<p>Aliquam elementum vulputate ipsum, et faucibus lorem sagittis quis.</p><p><a href='otherpage.html'>Link to relevant content</a></p>");
        });

        $("#changeText2").click(function() {
            $("#textBox").html("<p>Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus tempus fermentum leo nec tincidunt.</p><p><a href='otherpage.html'>Link to relevant content</a></p>");
        });

        $("#changeText3").click(function() {
            $("#textBox").html("<p>Vivamus id convallis augue. Nam scelerisque ante non sem tempor feugiat. Phasellus leo leo, malesuada in faucibus a, pellentesque id dui.</p><p><a href='otherpage.html'>Link to relevant content</a></p>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are literally linking between two different pages, there's no way for the scripts on either page to know anything about the other. Consider each page a blank slate. You have to pass information between the pages somehow and handle the content update on the new page.

You could put the code currently inside your click functions in a non-anonymous function and call that when the linked page loads, using a get parameter to identify which of the links was clicked and updating the content appropriately. (newpage.html?clicked=link1)

I suspect you're going about this in the wrong way though it's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks.  To clarify a bit more - there are two pages of content set up the same, the subjects are listed as links and when clicked/.click() the content appears.  At the end of the content on the first page I have a link to the related content on the second page (which as I've mentioned is set up the same way as the first page).  I want to be able to click on the link to the second page and bring up the content without having to click on the subject links.